# How to combine these jquery functions?

Tags: jquery, function

is there a way to combine these ?

```
$("#demo1Btn").mopTip({'w':200,'style':"overClick",'get':"#demo1"});
$("#demo2Btn").mopTip({'w':200,'style':"overClick",'get':"#demo2"});
$("#demo3Btn").mopTip({'w':200,'style':"overClick",'get':"#demo3"});
$("#demo4Btn").mopTip({'w':200,'style':"overClick",'get':"#demo4"});
$("#demo5Btn").mopTip({'w':200,'style':"overClick",'get':"#demo5"});
```

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  $("#demo" + i + "Btn").mopTip({'w':200,'style':"overClick",'get':"#demo" + i});
}
```

would be a bit cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Possibly with:

```
$('div[id^="demo"][id$="Btn"]').mopTip({'w':200,'style':"overClick",'get':this.id});
```

will select the elements whose `id` begins with "demo" and ends with "btn"; the `this.id` should find the relevant element's `id` and assign that to the `get` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could place all the class/id's on a same function, but just separate with comma.

```
$("#demo1Btn, #demo2Btn, #demo3Btn, #demo4Btn, #demo5Btn").mopTip({'w':200,'style':"overClick",'get':$(this).attr('id').replace('Btn','')});
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `starts-with` selector and an `each` loop

```
$("[id^='demo']").each(function(){
    $(this).mopTip({'w':200,'style':"overClick",'get':"#demo1"});
});
```